# Python remove not removing from list of two

Tags: python, list

So I'm trying the [Advent of Code 2021 day 3, part two](https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/3#part2).
**Edit:** the link only shows part one for those who didn't complete the challenge. I added part two at the end

The challenge is to get the correct code from a list by filtering out the incorrect ones.

*Read each index of each number and count the occurences of the characters 1 and 0. If 1 is the most common, keep those numbers that have 1 in that index, if it's 0, keep the ones with a 0, and move to the next index, repeat until only one possibility is left. If the count is a draw, keep the numbers with a 1 in that index*

Similar rules apply to the other code, which I'm not having trouble with. *Keep the digit with the fewer occurences and 0 if it's a draw.*

Code and full challenge description are at the end, please read the things I tried.

My code is correctly cleaning the list up to when two items are left.
The rules say when digit count at the index position idx is a draw, keep 1.

The filtering works fine as far as my debugging goes.

Things I tried:

- It's not a matter of changing the list while looping because I'm looping on a copy
- I tried different removal methods. `list.remove()`, `list.pop(index)` and list comprehension `i for i in o2_rating if i != item`. All the methods resulted in the same outcome

I did some debugging and I can confirm that

- The filtering works fine (each digit to keep, char, is correctly chosen)
- The draw condition works fine, using the same methods I can get the code for the least counted digit each index
- Given the draw condition works fine, I assume this happens when two items are remaining in a list.
- There is no invisible character

It's probably something dumb I'm missing but I fail to figure out what is

Here is the code

```py
def most_common_at_idx(idx, lst):
    idx_lst = []
    for item in lst:
        idx_lst.append(item[idx])
    return most_common_n(idx_lst)[-1] #return -1 index to prevent the "-" from passing

def most_common_n(lst):
    data = Counter(lst)

    two_most_common = data.most_common(2)
    # draw condition, draw in the counting
    if two_most_common[0][1] == two_most_common[1][1]:
        return '-1'

    return two_most_common[0][0]


sample = [
    "00100",
    "11110",
    "10110",
    "10111",
    "10101",
    "01111",
    "00111",
    "11100",
    "10000",
    "11001",
    "00010",
    "01010"
]

power_input = sample


# start with all the values
# gets the most counted number each digit
o2_rating = power_input.copy()
o2_code = ""

for idx in range(0, len(power_input[0])):
    # --- o2 ---
    print(o2_rating)
    if len(o2_rating) == 1:
        o2_code = o2_rating[0]
        break

    char = most_common_at_idx(idx, o2_rating)
    for item in o2_rating.copy():
        if item[idx] != char:
            o2_rating.remove(item)
```

This prints

```
['00100', '11110', '10110', '10111', '10101', '01111', '00111', '11100', '10000', '11001', '00010', '01010']
['11110', '10110', '10111', '10101', '11100', '10000', '11001']
['10110', '10111', '10101', '10000']
['10110', '10111', '10101']
['10110', '10111']
```

'10111' being the number I have to keep

[Full challenge](https://pastebin.com/kBTGm9b2), in pastebin so it doesn't clutter the post, hope it's not too hard to read

Comment: Could you post the problem statement? Seems like the link shows a different problem (perhaps day 3 part 1, and perhaps one should be logged to see part 2?)

Comment: @gimix sure, added at the end, hope it's not too hard to read

Comment: @gimix I just added a small summary of the rules

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working! You just don't keep track of the processing. If you print out `o2_rating` at the end, it holds:

['10111']

It would be better coding style (IMHO) to set up your code in a single function. This makes it more obvious that things are working, as well as more useful. Here's a hacked up version of your working code:

```
from collections import Counter

def most_common_at_idx(idx, lst):
    idx_lst = []
    for item in lst:
        idx_lst.append(item[idx])
    return most_common_n(idx_lst)[-1] #return -1 index to prevent the "-" from passing

def most_common_n(lst):
    data = Counter(lst)

    two_most_common = data.most_common(2)
    # draw condition, draw in the counting
    if two_most_common[0][1] == two_most_common[1][1]:
        return '-1'

    return two_most_common[0][0]

def solve_it(o2_rating):
    o2_code = "" 
    for idx in range(len(o2_rating[0])):
        # --- o2 ---
        print(o2_rating)
        if len(o2_rating) == 1:
            # getting here may be sample-dependent -- you may not need this at all
            o2_code = o2_rating[0]
            break

        char = most_common_at_idx(idx, o2_rating)
        for item in o2_rating.copy():
            if item[idx] != char:
                o2_rating.remove(item)
    print(o2_rating)
    o2_code = o2_code if o2_code else o2_rating[0] if o2_rating else None
    return o2_code

sample = [
    "00100",
    "11110",
    "10110",
    "10111",
    "10101",
    "01111",
    "00111",
    "11100",
    "10000",
    "11001",
    "00010",
    "01010"
]

This_prints = """
['00100', '11110', '10110', '10111', '10101', '01111', '00111', '11100', '10000', '11001', '00010', '01010']
['11110', '10110', '10111', '10101', '11100', '10000', '11001']
['10110', '10111', '10101', '10000']
['10110', '10111', '10101']
['10110', '10111']
"""

desired_answer = '10111' # being the number I have to keep
answer = solve_it(sample)
print("ANSWER IS: ", answer)
print("GOT IT!" if answer == desired_answer else "BUMMER!")
```

Comment: If I print o2_code it's just an empty string. Thanks to your reply I noticed len(o2_rating) is picking the equality to 1. But why is it not replacing o2_code with the only element remaining in the list? (o2_rating[0]

Comment: I'm running Py3.8 and my code runs properly. I would say that the issue with your finding length 1 and then breaking is that when you check in the fifth/last iteration, length is 2 when you check for length 1, and then the length gets set to 1 right afterwards. But by then you're done and are leaving the loop.